# JAVA javaFX menuBar, multiple items, one method (scene Builder)

Tags: java, javafx, scenebuilder

I have a window built with scene builder with a menuBar.
In the menuBar there are a couple of Menuitems that only open other windows.

So I want to write only one function that can be used by each one of those menuItems, and open the appropriate window.

I tried to give an id for each menuItem, and with this function

```
public void openWindow(ActionEvent event){ 
    System.out.println( event);
}
```

I can see that id (example :  customer menuItem) ,

```
javafx.event.ActionEvent[source=MenuItem[id=customers, styleClass=[menu-item]]]
```

But I dont know how to get it to use it to open the customer window.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to get id from ActionEvent you should cast the source of it to MenuItem:

```
public void openWindow(ActionEvent event){
    MenuItem source = (MenuItem) event.getSource();
    System.out.println(source.getId());
}
```

note, that if you are not sure that the source of event is of type MenuItem you can check it like so:

```
if (event.getSource() instanceof MenuItem) {
     MenuItem source = (MenuItem) event.getSource();
     System.out.println(source.getId());
}
```

Answer (score 3):

One option is to get the source of the event (the `MenuItem`) and retrieve some appropriate data from it (e.g. the `id` or the `userData`), as shown in other answers. This will work, but it feels a little fragile as you are relying on string binding and having to perform casts on the types all over the place.

I prefer in this situation just to define a separate method for handling each menu item. Obviously, you can still refactor common functionality into a separate method, in the usual way.

```
public class MyController {

    @FXML
    private void openCustomersWindow() {
        openWindow("/path/to/customers.fxml");
    }

    @FXML
    private void openOrdersWindow() {
        openWindow("/path/to/orders.fxml");
    }

    // ...

    private void openWindow(String resource) {
        try {
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource(resource));
            Scene scene = new Scene(loader.load());
            Stage newWindow = new Stage();
            newWindow.setScene(scene);
            newWindow.show();
        } catch (Exception exc) {
            // handle errors....
        }
    }

}
```

and then just use `onAction="#openCustomersWindow"` for one menu item and `onAction="#openOrdersWindow"` for another, etc.

Clearly, there is a little repeated code here, but it's not bad (certainly no worse than the amount of repetition in the FXML). If you had enough `MenuItem`s that this were problematic, you would probably want to consider defining them in Java code instead of FXML anyway.

Comment: I really like your approach. For serious commercial application I would definitely use this one. On the other hand for small apps I would stick with mine) anyway,  +1 from me